# convert content URI to FileUpload

Tags: android, kotlin, apollo-android

I get content URI from getContent and I want to convert it to FileUpload

```
  object upload : FileUpload(mimetype) {
    override fun contentLength(): Long {
      TODO("return contentLength here")
    }
    override fun fileName(): String? {
      TODO("return fileName to use in the multipart request here")
    }
    override fun writeTo(sink: BufferedSink) {
      TODO("write the data here")
    }
  }
```

Comment: Use `DocumentFile` to get the length and display name. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` to use to get the data to write to the `BufferedSink`. This is very reminiscent to creating an OkHttp/Retrofit `RequestBody` for a content `Uri`, and that is described in [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html) and [this blog post](https://cketti.de/2020/05/23/content-uris-and-okhttp/).

Comment: how to write to the BufferedSink from inputstream

Comment: That is covered in both of the blog posts that I linked to. Call `writeAll()` on the `BufferedSink`.